# How do I search for a range of values in between two Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, if-statement

First I know this is bad way to compare dates but I don't understand how to evaluate a strings to include the data between 2 values.  For example in this code how would I list not only transactions that occurred on tdate 1 and 2 but also the transactions that fell between them.

tdate information is set up like 11/07/2013

```
      System.out.println("Start Date: ");
      tdate = in.next();
      System.out.println("End Date: ");
      tdate2 = in.next();

      transactionSet trr = new transactionSet(); 

      for(int idx = 0; idx < ts.getNumTrans(); idx++){

        t = ts.retrieve(idx);
        if (t.getTdate().equals(tdate) || t.getTdate().equals(tdate2)){
         trr.insert(t);      
        }
      }
```

Comment: doesn't java have it's own date class?

Comment: You need to split the string by `/` then get the day (and possibly month and year), and then detect if its between them.  You could also use `DateFormat.parse(String)` to parse the string.

Comment: Use `Calendar` objects and see if it's within the boundaries.

Comment: *11/07/2013* This could be 11th July or 7th November, can you clarify which format exactly you're talking about?

Comment: Don't use `Calendar` objects.  They don't give you anything.

Comment: Ok so forgetting the dates example.  If I were looking for a people with first names that start with A but only go to D.  How would compare the the strings to include EVERYONE who has a name starting in that range?

Comment: That's a different question entirely.  Best if you post it as a new question.  Assuming somebody hasn't asked about **the compareTo method of the String class** already, of course.

Comment: Did you read the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) documentation? Especially the `compareTo` method?

Comment: I read the compareTo method but I don't understand how put the condition in since it cannot be >, <, ==, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");  // If this is the right format
Date first = format.parse(tdate);
Date second = format.parse(tdate2);
Date toCheck = format.parse(someDate);
if (toCheck.after(first) && toCheck.before(second)){
    // ...
}
```

You might want to do this in a try/catch block, in case the dates that are input are not formatted correctly.